# Install TensorFlow APIs using Docker environment

Tags: docker, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, deeplab

I want to train a model using Tensorflow, so to avoid problems of dependence between python, CUDA, Tensorflow....., I decided to use Docker.

To install Tensorflow I used these commands

```
# install nvidia docker
docker run --runtime=nvidia --rm nvidia/cuda:9.0-base nvidia-smi

# install tensorflow docker
docker pull tensorflow/tensorflow:1.12.0-gpu-py3

# run
docker run --runtime=nvidia -it --rm -v /$(pwd)/Desktop/DeepLab:/notebooks -p 8888:8888 tensorflow/tensorflow:1.12.0-gpu-py3
```

Now, I want to install DeepLab models, and to do this I have to clone the git repo into tensorflow/models/research/.

I do some research on the internet to learn how to add these folders or where we find the location of tensorflow -docker- installation, but no results.

So please, could anyone help me.

Thankyou